# Loosing session everytime Tomcat is restarted

Tags: jenkins, tomcat, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I am hosting my Jenkins Master on a Tomcat server. The issue is that when my Tomcat server is rebooted, it wipes out the whole session, and I have to reconfigure everytime my Jenkins master from scratch.

I looked a bit on the internet and saw that the session persistance is done in the **config.xml** file. The issue is that I do not have this file in META-INF, and even when I create it, it got deleted once I restart the server ...

How can I proceed ? Thanks

Comment: Tomcat version? Can you include your conf/server.xml and conf/context.xml. Also, your META-INF/context.xml. How are you deploying Tomcat? Stock download from tomcat.apache.org? package manager? Java buildpack? Thanks.

Comment: I am using this buildpack : https://github.com/Altoros/jenkins-buildpack that I deploy with Cloud Foundry with this command : 
`cf push app-name -p jenkins.war -m 512M -b https://github.com/Altoros/jenkins-buildpack` 
Unfortunately, I don't have a conf folder, neither a context.xml :(

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with that buildpack.

Answer (score 1):

In Cloud Foundry, the changes that you make to the filesystem are ephemeral which means that they are discarded as soon as the app restarts.

If you can determine the path where the changes are occurring, you can [bind a volume service](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/using-vol-services.html) to your app so that your changes are saved to an external CIFS or NFS share.

Alternatively, you can make changes to the config.xml in the directory that you are running `cf push` from. However, each time you change this file, you will need to run `cf push` again.